# SSH into server and create a directory in one line

Tags: ubuntu, bash, ssh

```
karl@karl-ux303ln:~$ ssh root@domain.com -t 'command; /bin/bash mkdir hello'
/bin/mkdir: /bin/mkdir: cannot execute binary file
Connection to domain.com closed.
```

I'm trying to ssh into my server and then run the command immediately.

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring the issues with using `root`, your question is still slightly unclear.  It could be you are trying to run `command` and then make directory `hello`, which can be done by:

```
ssh remote ' command ; bash -c "mkdir hello" '
```

On the other hand, if you are trying to run `command`, make directory `hello` and then be left in a shell with which you can interact, you could use this:

```
ssh -t remote ' command ; bash -c "mkdir hello" ; bash '
```

Answer (score 0):

1. It's never safe to connect to a server with `root@server`.
2. If you want to connect to a server and run a command in a one-liner you can use  `ssh [user]@[server] '[command]'`. Make sure you have the necessary rights before you run the command.

Comment: See also: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/82639